# How can i convert a svg image to png image with Imagemagick when the svg file has embedded images?

Tags: php, image, svg, imagemagick, png

With PHP i'm creating an image with embedded content (base64 encoded files). If i see it using Firefox, or downloading it and then opening it with Inkscape (www.inkscape.org), the image is fine!.

But when i try to convert it using imagemagick (using convert command or with Imagick support for PHP) the embedded image doesn't come in with the final result.

I don't know if there is a special command or configuration i'm missing. I'm not using any special setup. Just ...

```
convert image.svg image.png
```

Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick's built-in SVG rendering is really pretty horrible.  Don't use it if you can avoid it.  I'd recommend using [librsvg](https://live.gnome.org/LibRsvg) instead, either using the command-line [`rsvg`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsvg) tool, or possibly with the [PHP rsvg extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/rsvg).

(Librsvg's rendering isn't always perfect either, but it *should* be able to handle embedded images just fine.  If you want even better rendering, you could always try [using Inkscape from the command line](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Can_Inkscape_be_used_from_the_command_line.3F).)

Comment: I am trying to get this installed on my windows dev machine, and don't find much  guide on this. Is this possible to get librsvg configured on windows so that image magick can render the svg files properly?

Comment: @noobcode: I've never tried it, but at least according to [this page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Image_administration#SVG), Inkscape may be more convenient to set up as an SVG renderer on Windows than rsvg.

Answer (score 1):

Is the embedded image in PNG or in Jpeg format? What converter is used in PHP? I tried on Windows with latest ImageMagick, which doesn't come with RSVG. I found a [RSVG-Converter build for Windows,](http://opensourcepack.blogspot.fr/2012/06/rsvg-convert-svg-image-conversion-tool.html) and, while it does a good job, it skips the Jpeg version of the image of [a test file](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/svg/struct-image-04-t.svg).

On the other hand, the built-in converter handles correctly both images, but does an awful job on the [home image](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/home.svg) shown in the [SVG tutorial](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#svg).

Comment: I'm under linux, so RSVG would be the choice. Although in the shared hosting service i'm willing to use they don't have RSVG ... so i'll have to solve it using imagemagick or GD.